# PHP Composer [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 61

Tags: php, curl, composer-php

```
$ php composer.phar require predis/predis


https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 61 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands identity content encodings.), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

                                                                                                                                                                         
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                                               
  curl error 61 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/predis/predis.json: Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands identity content encodings.  
                                                                                                                                                                         

require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I installed new curl on Ubuntu 16.04
curl 7.63.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.63.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1j nghttp2/1.7.1
Release-Date: 2018-12-12
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy

and now composer cant install anything from packagist

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 might be pretty old. Which version of PHP and Composer are you using?

Comment: I removed curl and reinstalled it from apt. Now everything works.